# How to keep only the paths to the leaves in a directory tree?

Tags: javascript

I have this array of directory paths (strings):

```
let arr = [
  '0',
  '2',
  '0\\0-1',
  '2\\2-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-1'
]
```

The trees of directories would look like this (note that `0-1`, `2-0-0-0`, and `2-0-0-1` are the leaves):

```
0
|_ 0-1

2
|_ 2-0
   |_ 2-0-0
      |_ 2-0-0-0
      |_ 2-0-0-1
```

From this array, I want to keep only the paths to the leaves. This means that I want to remove all elements, except `0\0-1`, `2\2-0\2-0-0\2-0-0-0`, and `2\2-0\2-0-0\2-0-0-1`. My new array should look like this:

```
newArr = [
  '0\\0-1',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-0',
  `2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-1`
]
```

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: Don't have the time to answer this well, but you might want to check out the String method `startsWith` and use that inside a function to check the string to the rest of the array. It's an easy question, but hard to optimize for performance.

Comment: Is the array guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, it is guaranteed to be sorted because I have written a recursive function to produce this sorted output

Comment: @6cloud9 If you're generating these, wouldn't it be even easier to just produce the array with only the leaves?

Comment: @Bergi Not really - the directory IDs are produced from a bunch of selected nodes in a hierarchical tree, and I can only retrieve all the selected nodes (can't just select the children). So, based on each ID, I can tell what the path to each node is, and from those paths, I only needed the paths to the leaves.

Comment: @6cloud9 Still, in your function you can check if the recursive call did return something, and only if it did return an empty result then produce the current path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested by DexieTheSheep, using `startsWith`

```js
let arr = [
  '0',
  '2',
  '0\\0-1',
  '2\\2-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-1'
];

const result = arr.filter(item => !arr.some(ex => ex.startsWith(item + '\\')));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good solution because it uses just one line of code, but users should be adviced this would be extremely slow on large arrays since it has a complexity of O(n^2), while this problem can be solved as O(n).

Comment: @Daniels118 OP says the array is sorted, so you only need to check `arr[i+1].startsWith(…)`

Comment: @Bergi this is exactly what I'm saying :)

Answer (score 1):

This would also work

```
let arr = [
  '0',
  '2',
  '0\\0-1',
  '2\\2-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-0',
  '2\\2-0\\2-0-0\\2-0-0-1'
]

arr.forEach((item, itemIndex) => {
    if (!arr.some((o, oIndex) => oIndex !== itemIndex && o.startsWith(item))) {
        console.log(item);
    }
});
```